# Using "locksettings" to manage a 4x4 lock pattern?

Tags: lock-screens, shell, android-11, pattern-lock

I'm running Android 11 on a Pixel 5.

I know about the `locksettings --set-pattern ...` shell command, but that command only seems to work in a 3x3 pattern space. For example, if the pattern is to start at the upper left and in a clockwise direction to touch each corner of a 3x3 lock-pattern square, I can set that pattern lock as follows (because the pattern dots are numbered 1 through 9) ...

```
locksettings --set-pattern 1397
```

However, my ROM also offers the option of 4x4, 5x5, and 6x6 pattern spaces (dots numbered 1 through 16 for 4x4, and 1 through 25 for 5x5, and 1 through 36 for 6x6). If I want to do the same clockwise traversal to the corners in a 4x4 pattern space, the numbers would be 1, 4, 16, 13. However, I don't know a way to specify these 4 numeric values to the `locksettings --set-pattern ...` command.

Is there any way to use `locksettings --set-pattern ...` in a 4x4, 5x5, or 6x6 pattern space?

If not, is there any way to run some other shell command(s) under Android 11 to set a lock pattern in a 4x4, 5x5, or 6x6 pattern space?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: not sure I got the question https://blog.alxu.ca/unlocking-large-pattern-encryption-in-twrp.html

Comment: @alecxs that looks like a possible answer, though it seems only for TWRP.

Comment: On the other hand, looks like [AOSP hardcoded the pattern only for 3x3](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java;l=855;drc=fe54112f40c78e99ed63a75a52f3f137df0c6477), so for custom implementation, it needs to be checked with the ROM maker whether they also support/modify this part or not.

Comment: Yes, and thank you, @AndrewT. I want this to run via adb for a running ROM, not for TWRP.  And my ROM (crDroid) supports 4x4, 5x5, and 6x6 in addition to 3x3, but the "locksettings" utility that comes with my ROM only seems to support 3x3. So, I'll check with the crDroid developers about this.

Comment: @alecxs - OK, so does this mean that I can use this method via ADB in a running ROM to set the lock pattern, in place of using "locksettings set-pattern"? If so, I just need to figure out how to somehow build the method as a stand-alone executable which can then be installed on my device.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work on my device ...
<NEWLINE>130|redfin:/ # locksettings set-pattern '159=>?@<84'<NEWLINE>
Error while executing command: set-pattern<NEWLINE>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credential can't be null or empty<NEWLINE>
... followed by a stack trace

Comment: Yes, it works with 1397, whether quotes are present or not. The way the shell works, the presence or absence of quotes around "1397" is irrelevant. Quotes only matter when passing spaces or special characters as part of a command-line argument. I'll try "set-password" a little later today and post my results here.

Comment: I'm not using backtick. When I write "quote", I specifically mean a quote character, not a backtick character. Anyway, `locksettings set-password 1397` and `locksettings set-password "1397"` and `locksettings set-password '1397'` all work for me, which is not surprising, since the shell sends the same arguments to the command in all three cases.

Comment: And yes, sending 1397 in the 3x3 world is indeed what's needed for the 4 corners of the square when traversed clockwise. And it indeed seems like a dead end for me with crdroid ... at least when using "locksettings". But could there perhaps be another way to accomplish what I want? ... perhaps by using sqlite3 and modifying some sort of system database?

Comment: On my device, 1397 works for me as a pattern unlock on a 3x3 screen. In any case, I want 4x4, and I want to be able to enable/disable it via the "locksettings" utility. And I now realize that I'm probably out of luck on my device.